# mechanize stuck on page loading till timeout while regular browsers work fine, no javascript/ajax

Tags: python, mechanize

Using python and mechanize im trying to login to web-site.

The code i'm using is:

```
    from mechanize import Browser

def calOnline(uname,passwd):
    br = Browser()
    br.set_debug_http(True)
    br.set_debug_redirects(True)  
    br.set_debug_responses(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(True)
    #~ br.encoding()
    br.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1'),
        ('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
        ('Accept-Language','en-us,en;q=0.5'),
        ('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate'),
        ('Connection','keep-alive')]
    print('opening site')
    br.open('https://m.cal-online.co.il/')
    print('\n\nsubmiting first form')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.submit()
    print('\n\nselecting login form')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br['ctl00$cphMain$LGN$UserName'] = uname
    br['ctl00$cphMain$LGN$Password'] = passwd
    print('\n\nsubmitting form')
    br.submit(name='ctl00$cphMain$LGN$LoginButton')
    print('\n\nOpening details page')
    res = br.open('https://m.cal-online.co.il/SCREENS/Transactions/TrSearch.aspx')
    print res.read()


uname = 'someuname'
passwd = 'somepasswd'   
a = calOnline(uname, passwd)
print a.read()
```

The website is mobile version of credit card website from which im trying to get my expenses.

Browser (Android as mobile or Firefox/Chrome/Opera as desktop) opens the site and logs in without any issue.
While trying to login programatically it just stuck, here is debug log with iOS user-agent:

```
opening site
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449; Path=/; Secure
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:44:52 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 302
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /SCREENS/AccountManagement/HomePage.aspx HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Location: https://m.cal-online.co.il/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Opening.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSCREENS%2fAccountManagement%2fHomePage.aspx
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:44:53 GMT
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /SCREENS/AccountManagement/Opening.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSCREENS%2fAccountManagement%2fHomePage.aspx HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:44:55 GMT
header: Cache-Control: private
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 1256
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Location: https://m.cal-online.co.il/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?cc=c009a07&rnd=2103197098
header: Set-Cookie: test_cookie=ok; expires=Sat, 30-Jun-2012 21:45:12 GMT; path=/
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:45:07 GMT
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?cc=c009a07&rnd=2103197098 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: test_cookie=ok; JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=clocqc55tdzykh45zql10045; path=/; HttpOnly
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:45:09 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 3153
header: Connection: close


submiting first form
send: 'POST /SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?rnd=2103197098&cc=c009a07 HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 189\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nReferer: https://m.cal-online.co.il/\r\nCookie: test_cookie=ok; ASP.NET_SessionId=clocqc55tdzykh45zql10045; JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n__VIEWSTATE=&ctl00%24__MATRIX_VIEWSTATE=1&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24UserName=&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24Password=&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24LoginButton.x=1&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24LoginButton.y=1'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:45:10 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 3210
header: Connection: close


selecting login form


submitting form
send: 'POST /SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?rnd=2103197098&cc=c009a07 HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 206\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nReferer: https://m.cal-online.co.il/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?rnd=2103197098&cc=c009a07\r\nCookie: test_cookie=ok; ASP.NET_SessionId=clocqc55tdzykh45zql10045; JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n__VIEWSTATE=&ctl00%24__MATRIX_VIEWSTATE=2&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24UserName=<uname>&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24Password=<passwd>&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24LoginButton.x=1&ctl00%24cphMain%24LGN%24LoginButton.y=1'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Location: https://m.cal-online.co.il/SCREENS/AccountManagement/HomePage.aspx
header: Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=478FDDCD007398FEB264895D0F6EDB51B391DD0F5FBA3C71FC6A9E747AF3A97E6382E7B939614DFC07B25A1D4A641ED121F15508483A676AC49BAA550BEADF382F93792E849F63E99B03FA45143391ACD5E18CA7124FAC43AC378D16703DB5B2A374E4D1B3278BF9B886F3B4A41BB12E3569162D; path=/; HttpOnly
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:45:14 GMT
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /SCREENS/AccountManagement/HomePage.aspx HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16\r\nHost: m.cal-online.co.il\r\nCookie: test_cookie=ok; ASP.NET_SessionId=clocqc55tdzykh45zql10045; .ASPXAUTH=478FDDCD007398FEB264895D0F6EDB51B391DD0F5FBA3C71FC6A9E747AF3A97E6382E7B939614DFC07B25A1D4A641ED121F15508483A676AC49BAA550BEADF382F93792E849F63E99B03FA45143391ACD5E18CA7124FAC43AC378D16703DB5B2A374E4D1B3278BF9B886F3B4A41BB12E3569162D; JSESSIONID=E46452F3D9D4B7303C6E93F04BE54449\r\nReferer: https://m.cal-online.co.il/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?rnd=2103197098&cc=c009a07\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: X-MA-MIS-Device: root^html^mozilla/5^safari^appleiphone^appleiphone(os_3.0)
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
header: Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2012 21:45:16 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 5235
header: Connection: close
```

Same stuff happens with my Firefox User-agent. It just getting stuck on this moment till timeout on website which in place redirect me to LogOut page due to inactivity.
Is there something I'm missing out? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something that strikes we as strange: Second to last header reply in Set-Cookie has HttpOnly, but the location is https

Comment: You can notice that Set-Cookie in header just before submission of first form is HttpOnly too, which doesn't prevent the script to keep runing.